# Working with database objects per FK / user in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a question about handling objects per user with forms. I want to interact only with the objects related to the logged in user.

If I submit a form it checks every object in the database and gives a returned 2! error when there are 2 objects with the same `product_id`. 
I use the `product_id` field for the barcode and they are unique per product and some users work with the same product.

I try to find a way to isolate the user objects first and then work with the database. Or is there another way to handle this issue?

As far as I found out, `objects.filter(user=request.user)` will not work, because I need the `objects.get` to match the `barcode_input` of the form field with a certain database field in order to reduce the quantity.

I searched a lot before asking this question, but i'm out of technical keywords to search for.

models.py

```
class ProductModel(models.Model):
user                = models.ForeignKey(User)
sku                 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
product_id          = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=False)
category            = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity            = models.IntegerField(default=0)
amount_sold         = models.IntegerField(default=0)


def __str__(self):
    return self.product_line
```

forms.py

```
class ScanProductForm(forms.Form):
barcode_input = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
amount_input = forms.IntegerField(initial=1)

def clean_barcode_input(self):
    barcode_input = self.cleaned_data['barcode_input']
    qs = ProductModel.objects.filter(product_id=barcode_input)

    if qs.exists():
        return barcode_input

    raise forms.ValidationError("Barcode does not exist")
```

views.py

```
def barscan_view(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.ScanProductForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        barcode_input = form.cleaned_data.get("barcode_input")
        amount_input = form.cleaned_data.get("amount_input")
        p = ProductModel.objects.get(product_id=barcode_input)
        if p.user.username == request.user.username:
            if p.quantity >= 0 and amount_input <= p.quantity:
                p.amount_sold = F("amount_sold") + amount_input
                p.quantity = F("quantity") - amount_input
                p.save()
                messages.success(request, '%s - %s was successfully scanned' % (p.product_line, p.sku))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('overview/scan/')
            else:
                if p.quantity > 0:
                    messages.error(request, 'Only %s in stock' %p.quantity) 
                elif p.quantity is 0:
                    messages.error(request, 'This product is out of stock')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'ID does not match any of your stock')
else:
    form = forms.ScanProductForm()
return render(request, 'maninv/scan_product.html', {'form': form})
```

Thanks, Sander

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a slightly re-design of your view logic will help you achieve the desired result. You could change the `ScanProductForm` form to be a `ModelForm` of `ProductModel`. Then, you could first retrieve the `ProductModel` instance using the `barcode_input` + `request.user`.

**forms.py**

```
class ScanProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    barcode_input = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus': 'autofocus'}))
    amount_input = forms.IntegerField(initial=1)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        fields = ('barcode_input', 'amount_input')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        amount_input = cleaned_data.get('amount_input')
        if self.instance.quantity == 0:
            self.add_error(None, 'This product is out of stock')
        elif amount_input > self.instance.quantity:
            self.add_error(None, 'Only %s in stock' % self.instance.quantity)
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        product = super().save(commit=False)
        amount_input = cleaned_data.get('amount_input')
        product.amount_sold = F('amount_sold') + amount_input
        product.quantity = F('quantity') - amount_input
        if commit:
            product.save()
        return product
```

**views.py**

```
def barscan_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        product = None
        barcode = request.POST.get('barcode_input')
        queryset = ProductModel.objects.filter(product_id=barcode)
        if queryset.exists():
            try:
                # the queryset is already filtered by the barcode
                # now we apply an extra filter to check if this user has the product
                product = queryset.get(user=request.user)
            except ProductModel.DoesNotExist:
                # here we are sure this product exists, but this user doesnt have it in the stock.
                messages.error(request, 'ID does not match any of your stock.')
        else:
            # here we know this product doesnt exist
            messages.error(request, 'Barcode does not exist.')

        if product is not None:
            form = forms.ScanProductForm(request.POST, instance=product)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, '%s - %s was successfully scanned' % (product.product_line, product.sku))
                return HttpResponseRedirect('overview/scan/')

    else:
        form = forms.ScanProductForm()
    return render(request, 'maninv/scan_product.html', {'form': form})
```

But there is a small change on some error handling. Some stuff that was communicated to the user via `messages.error` is now a non field error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply! I'm trying to understand the code and it makes more and more sense :-) It gives an error when I hit the add button while the input is a barcode that exists : Exception Value:  

name 'cleaned_data' is not defined

Comment: I've got it working and learned a few new django practices :-) thank you very much!